# How to create a list of 5 next numbers that are not divided by 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

dear community, I started learning Python and want to create a list of 5 next (after the given number) numbers that are not divided by 3 (modulo).
Here is my code:

```
def main(N):
    
#print a list of 5 next numbers that are not divided by 3
    l = list()
    for i in range(int(N), 150):
        if len(l) < 5:
            if i%3==0:
                l.append(i+1)
    return [l]
```

at the end I get f.e. for the `print(main(99))`:

`>>> [100, 103, 106, 109, 112]`

I also tried to put i+=1 after if statement but in the end I got even weirder result:

`[101, 101, 102, 104, 104]`

What do I do wrong and how can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: What is `5 next numbers`

Comment: Also what is this line supposed to do? `if len(l) < 5:`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: You're _only_ appending numbers that are 1 greater than numbers divisible by 3. In other words, you're checking each number, and only adding to the list when you find one `i%3==0`

Comment: what about checking `i % 3 != 0` and appending that number to the list?

Answer (score 2):

I would write a generator that yields numbers not divisible by 3 with a base number and count as arguments:

```
def three_no_factor(n, cnt):
    x = 1
    while x <= cnt:
        if n % 3 != 0:
            yield n
            x += 1
        n += 1
```

Then use that to get the list of 5 numbers not divisible by 3:

```
>>> [x for x in three_no_factor(100,5)]
[100, 101, 103, 104, 106]
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way for sure

Comment: Thanks!! I will have to read more on `yield`

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a specific reason to cap the values at 150, you can just let the loop run until the list is full.

```py
def next_nontriples(N):
# return a list of 5 next numbers that are not divisible by 3
    ls = list()
    nx = N + 1
    while len(ls) < 5:
        if nx%3 != 0:
            ls.append(nx)
        nx += 1
    return ls
```

Using the `!=` operator is the key. Note that I'm returning the resulting list, whereas you return a list that has the required list as its only element, due to the extra square brackets around your `return` item.

You can fill the list once per loop-5-times too:

```py
def next_nontriples(N):
# return a list of 5 next numbers that are not divisible by 3
    ls = list()
    nx = N + 1
    for ix in range(5):
        if nx%3 == 0:
            nx += 1 # skip this one 
        ls.append(nx)
        nx += 1
    return ls
```

Here we just add an increment to our candidate value if it fails the test (by being divisible by three). We know that the next number will qualify.

Finally you could just handle the three cases separately. Not recommended particularly here but hard-coding is sometimes your friend:

```py
def next_nontriples(N):
# return a list of 5 next numbers that are not divisible by 3
    if N%3 == 0:
        return [N+1, N+2, N+4, N+5, N+7]
    if N%3 == 1:
        return [N+1, N+3, N+4, N+6, N+7]
    if N%3 == 2:
        return [N+2, N+3, N+5, N+6, N+8]
```

Comment: I considered doing a list comprehension but I think it would only confuse matters.

Comment: thank you a lot for the explanations! no there's no reason for 150, I just didn't know how to start the list from my given number without in range

Comment: Sure, I wasn't sure if you knew about `while` loops - basically repeating until the condition becomes false (at the loop).

Answer (score 0):

Another way - >

```
def main(N):
    gen = (i for i in range(int(N), 150) if i % 3 != 0)  # create generator
    return [next(gen) for j in range(5)]  # iterate 5 times


main(99) # [100, 101, 103, 104, 106]
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way to do this that I can think of. :)